# Question on homogenous ODE $xyy'= y^2 - x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Working on a problem from a textbook that goes like:
$$xyy'= y^2 - x^2,$$
where $y(-1) = 2$. I have worked the problem down to
$$y = \pm x \sqrt{c-2\ln(x)}$$
and then solving for $c$ given the initial condition I get $4$.

When writing out the final particular solution, the textbook has $-x\sqrt{4-2\ln(x)}$. I have trouble understanding why the $x$ is negative out front. Does it have to do with the $\pm$ from square rooting earlier? Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you sure the initial condition is $y(-1)=2$? This gives $ 2 = \mp \sqrt{c-2\pi i}$ or $c = 4 + 2\pi i.$ Are you missing a minus sign somewhere? Did you forget an absolute value as in $\ln|x|$? Is the initial condition actually $y(1)=2$?

Comment: It should be $\ln(|x|)$. It is the graph of $y =  -x \sqrt{4-2\ln(|x|)}$ which contains the point $(-1,2)$.

Comment: I actually have an issue with that solution, however. The actual solution is $y^2=x^2(4-\ln(|x|))$ unless one specifies that that $y$ must be a *function* of $x$.

Comment: It should be the absolute value of x in ln(x)

Comment: @Gobi you can edit the question to reflect this

Comment: You found that the solution is 

$$y = \pm x\sqrt {c - 2 \ln|x|}$$ 

where $c=4.$ Notice that the positive solution $y = x\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|x|}$ **doesn't** satisfy the initial condition as $$y(-1)=-1\sqrt{4-2\ln|-1|}=-\sqrt{4}=-2\neq 2.$$
However, $y = -x\sqrt {4 - 2 \ln|x|}$ does satisfy the initial condition.